# How to fix "'default' errored after 3.27 s" while trying to use gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

i've got this issue while trying using gulp:

```
[13:41:01] 'default' errored after 3.27 s
```

and after that process stopped.

[issue screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfw8w.png)

Comment: *Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/scss/fonts.scss'*

Comment: oh, thanks, I saw it but I thought that problem isn't in this line, because process stopped after default error